# How to recover deleted file when it is deleted from recycle bin

Tags: windows-8

I had deleted many files from recycle bin I want to know if I could recover them .can you tell me the procedure.

Comment: You need to use some recovery software (like recuva). The sectors in the hard drive might not be overwritten yet.

Comment: Sometimes it's not deleted from recycle bin. Open `C:\$RECYCLE.BIN` and find the file. Otherwise use Recuva.

Comment: I will try recuva . thanks alot. But can you tell me recuva recovers deleted movies

Comment: Your chances of fully undeleting a movie are quite low (but it depends on the size of the movie and how fragmented your disk are).  Generally you would be better off getting another copy of the movie.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single procedure - it depends on the type of files and type of hard drive.  In the simplistic case - ie something which might allow partial recovery - something like Recuva as mentioned, or Photorec can scan through the disk and look for file signatures - this has limitations in that it looses filenames, will probably come up with multiple revisions of files and does not work well on large files on fragmented drives.

If it is a FAT based filesystem you may be able to use undelete, and if it is an NTFS based filesystem you may be able to use ntfsundelete - these are the best options if they work.

Note: before attempting recovery it is best to do a bit copy of the drive, so that if something goes wrong, you are not in a worse position then when you started.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: if the files are important, you recover them from a backup copy, which is a must have for important files.

Long answer: if the files are important, but you don't have a backup copy, you need to use a file recovery program. Since you said recycle bin, I assume you use Windows. Explicitly stating your OS in the question would've been a good idea, since answers to your question are OS specific. You can try [recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) for example. But if the deleted files are really important, don't do it yourself. Since you've resorted to ask this question, most likely you lack knowledge to do it right yourself. Shut down your computer to minimize the risk of disk sectors that contain the deleted files to be overwritten and pay a data recovery professional to do the job. Warning: it's not cheap.

Comment: You can safely attempt this yourself, provided you first do a bit copy of the drive.  As there is no hardware failure, any recovery is going to be done in software, so a bitcopy won't damage things.

Comment: @davidgo I wouldn't call imaging a drive an easier task than just running some GUI file recovery software, that's why I explicitly warned against attempting it.

Comment: Note that sometimes Windows likes to install a bunch of updates at shutdown, and downloading & installing any program (like recuva) could overwrite the file fragments. And if you were running linux, an image is as simple as `dd if=/dev/sdXn of=image`